# Can't find related Attribute using Mapstruct Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, mapper

I am following the following document for implementing a mapper interface:
[MapStruct- Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) for Employee and EmployeeDTO.

Here is my Employee Class:

```
public class Employee {
private int id;
private String name;
// getters and setters
}
```

Here is my EmployeeDTO class:

```
public class EmployeeDTO {
private int employeeId;
private String employeeName;
// getters and setters
}
```

Here is my Mapper code:

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {
@Mapping(target="employeeId", source="entity.id")
@Mapping(target="employeeName", source="entity.name")
EmployeeDTO employeeToEmployeeDTO(Employee entity);

@Mapping(target="id", source="dto.employeeId")
@Mapping(target="name", source="dto.employeeName")
Employee employeeDTOtoEmployee(EmployeeDTO dto);
}
```

I am getting "**Can't find related attribute**" by hovering over entity.id. entity.name, dto.employeeId and dto.employeeName.

Why is it so? It is working fine if I am removing the dot operation on entity and dto and just writing the fields name.

Comment: are you sure you have added the dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, `<parameter>.<field>` should be used when there are multiple mapping sources to refer to the right parameter. But field names can be used directly when the mapping method has only one source parameter.

There is a plugin for IntelliJ, [Mapstruct Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10036-mapstruct-support), which provides code completion and other features for projects that use Mapstruct. After installing it, the `Can't find related attribute` error no longer appears in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same it is working fine for me with dot operator. Maybe try adding the annotationProcessorPaths section to the configuration part of the maven-compiler-plugin plugin present in the baeldung [document](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct)

This plugin given in the document:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Try if it helps

Answer (score 0):

put @Entity above Employee and EmployeeDTO class

Comment: DTO is not an Entity.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to use @Data on the EmployeeDTO class and @Entity on Employee class